# Whats the best way to define global variables for common fields in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, next.js

For my Next.js Web-App, I want to **define some sort of global variables for common values**, which I then can **reuse all over the application**, in order to have a single location where common variables are defined, save writing and also make future modifications much easier (as the value only has to be changed at one place).

Main use case: **Text Fields**, e.g.

```
COMPANY_NAME = "XYZ Ltd."
COMPANY_SLOGAN = "We love stack overflow."
COMPANY_MAIL = "contact@xyz.io"
```

Everywhere I searched, I read that in Next.js **env Variables could be used** (e.g. with process.env.COMPANY_NAME), but **is env really the correct place** for defining simple text fields as per my main use case?
I'm also aware that **props could be used** which are then passed on to all components, but if thats the best-practice, where's the correct place to define them?

To take it one step further, also language localization would be a possible use case for these global variables (e.g. all values for EN and DE). Can this be solved in a similar way?

Thank you for your expertise.

Comment: You can create a js file, define all the constants there, and export it. Import them wherever you want.

Comment: Are these global variables or global constants? Global constants you can just put in any file and export. Global variables are a mistake and are never the solution to almost any problem with Next/React.

Comment: @NickBailey global constants. they should not be changed throughout all pages. e.g. COMPANY_NAME should always stay the same.

Comment: @rahuuzz I thought about that. Whats the best location to import them, if I only want to import them at one place of the whole project. Could it be _app or _document? I don't have too much clue about that. Thank you for your help

Comment: @jay you could import it in your desired pages and use it directly. If you want it in every page inside pages directory then you could pass it through _app.js along with pageProps. I wouldnt recommend _document.